# Xamarin.Forms.Lottie 2.5.4 is not Working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, lottie

I am installing Xamarin.Forms.Lottie 2.5.4 from Nuget.

I used the code from [this sample](https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin/tree/develop/Samples/Forms) but as soon as I run it gives error

> Could not resolve type with token 0100007c (from typeref, class/assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute, netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)

Now, what can I do?

I am using VS2017 Version15.2 (26430.14) (community)

Comment: The new Lottie.Forms versions are targeting .NETStandard instead of PCL. You need to upgrade your app to be using .NETStandard instead.
Check out this 
https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/